# How do I collect the keys of all true values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, while-loop

This is slightly modified version of the code in the PHP docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

```
<?php

$array = array(
    -1 => true,
    0 => false,
    1 => true
);

while ($bet = current($array)) {
    if ($bet == true) {
        echo key($array) . '<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}
?>
```

This is as close as I could get to what I wanted.

This this echoes "-1", and I DO understand why.

What I want to know is how to modify this code so that it will continue searching for "true" values even after it encounters an false (and not just for an array of 3 values).

I realize this might not be the best way of doing it and I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance!!

Trufa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo join("<br>", array_keys(array_filter($array)));
```

`array_filter` returns true values when you don't supply a callback method, `array_keys` gets you the keys for those values, then prep it for output using `join`

Comment: And to explain: array_filter() without second argument will remove all array elements whose value evalulates to false. (it will also remove 0-s for example).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of [`array_filter`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_keys`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$array = array(
  -1 => true,
  0 => false,
  1 => true
);

$keys = array_keys(array_filter($array));
echo join("<br />", $keys);
```

See this in action at http://www.ideone.com/AREmK.

`array_keys` returns an array containing they keys of the given array. `array_filter` lets you filter elements out of an array based on a callback function. If no callback is given, as the manual states:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE  (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

Note that this will also filter out values that are [*falsy*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). If you want to only filter values that are explicitly `false`:

```
function filter_false($val)
{
  return $val !== false; // if $val is not false, it'll be kept
}
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($array, 'filter_false'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the entire array:

```
foreach ($bet as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == true) echo $key . "<br/>";
}
```

edit: no?.. hmm.. another method:

```
while (list($key,$value) = each($bet)) { 
  if ($value) echo $key . "<BR/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct `while($bet = current($array))` will only continue looping so long as the current array element evaluates to `true`. In general `while` loops imply that you're looping until some condition is met.

If you want to perform an action on every element of an array, you should use a `for` or `foreach` loop, which more clearly state your intent to iterate over the entire array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {

}

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
  if ($value == true) echo $key . "<br/>"; 
}
```